# Different Font size for Unicode Font

Tags: css, unicode, joomla, fonts

I'm setting up a multilingual Joomla site where the user can choose the language. Say - English and Tibetan. Everything looks fine on English but when viewing on Tibetan site, the fonts are too small. If I increase the font size then the English site's fonts become bigger too since they both use the same CSS file.

Is there a way where I can set different font sizes for the Tibetan Font and the English Font using the same CSS file??

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:lang` css pseudo-class and for example set it on the `html` tag like this:

```
html:lang(en) h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

html:lang(bo) h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

According to [HTML Language Code Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp) you should use `bo` for the tibetan language. You can also read more about the `:lang` pseudo-class [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang).

Comment: thank you so much Topr..  that was so really helpful.  I'll try that now